# Does DQN take into account past states?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I'm using an implementation of DQN to train an agent for a kind of game (arxiv.org/abs/1312.5602). I wanted to know if DQN agents will take actions based on history of past states/actions or just the current state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard DQN architecture as presented in the original "*Human level control through deep reinforcement learning*" Nature paper actually takes as input the 4 last states to take a decision.

Using $k$ last states could work in some situations, however it limits the scope of available "memory". Using recurrent neural networks could be another solution to look into (see DRQN).

Comment: The original DQN algorithm actually concatenated the last four (I think) frames as the current state. This effectively gave the algorithm a measure of velocity of moving objects. Most RL algorithms assume that their environments are markov i.e. there is enough information in the current state to predict a future state. Concatenating the frames as suggested is a relaxation of this assumption. And as rightly suggested, using recurrent architectures takes this relaxation to the extreme.

Comment: True, thanks! I edited the answer. Great note on the markov properties of RL problems too!

Comment: Technically, the DQN does not take "last 4 states", but uses the last  4 frames as its state (with the aim of making it a better approximation of a Markov state than the data from a single frame). Even the whole history of all frames and actions in the episode up to a point can be considered a single state, just not a very practical one.